# What's the word 'have' in "I'll have you lend me yours if you think mine is better"?

Tags: meaning

> I'll **have** you lend me yours if you think mine is better!

If you were to rephrase this sentence, what other verb in place of that 'have' would you use instead?

Comment: If I wanted that meaning, I wouldn't change any words...Usually if you change the words you change the meaning.  Is the "causative have" https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/causatives-have-get.html  The meaning is odd, so I wonder what you are actually trying to say.  Where did you find this sentence?

Comment: @JamesK I saw that in some TV show. Someone wanted to trade a copycat stuff that they had made themselves for an original item with the original creator by somewhat forcibly making them use the copycat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example, "have" means "cause it to happen" or "make it happen".

A similar example is "I'll **have** you arrested for hitting me", which means "I will make you get arrested for hitting me".

So you can say "I'll **make** you lend me yours..."